# Configuring Apache for HTTP to HTTPS and SSL Termination

Tags: apache2

I am running a couple containers on a host that are only listening for HTTP.  I'm trying to configure Apache to perform the following:

- Redirect any requests on port 80 to 443
- Connect to the backend servers over HTTP
- All client to Apache connections are HTTPS

Below is my current configuration.  ipam-1 loads with some resources missing, though I believe that's an app config issue.  Semaphore throws a Bad Request error indicating I'm talking in HTTP, but the server expects HTTPS.  If I visit each site by IP, they load fine. My SSL settings are defined in the ssl.conf module since I'm using a wildcard certificate.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ipam-1
    ServerAlias ipam-1.gruntlabs.net
    Redirect permanent / https://ipam-1.gruntlabs.net
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName semaphore
    ServerAlias semaphore.gruntlabs.net
    Redirect permanent / https://semaphore.gruntlabs.net
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName ipam-1
    ServerAlias ipam-1.gruntlabs.net

    ProxyPass / http://172.16.0.40:25800/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://172.16.0.40:25800/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName semaphore
    ServerAlias semaphore.gruntlabs.net

    ProxyPass / http://172.16.0.40:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://172.16.0.40:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```